# Why voltage decrease in battery when more current is drawn from it?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current

I have a load which needs around 12V and 6.5A. When I connect a 12V battery pack with 4400mah capacity with no load then the output voltage shown is 12.3V but when I connect my load the voltage tends to drop to 10.4 V. I assume the reason is because of internal resistance, but still I am not sure. Can anyone help me out here? Apart from this is there any other way to retain the same voltage to draw the same current rate, so the power remains same?

Comment: Depending on the type of load you have, you maybe be able mitigate the voltage drop, but your best bet is a better (or additional) battery(s) .

Comment: Ya ... Because V = E - Ir .... So when I increases, V decreases.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like its internal resistance, from your measurements its value is around 0,3 ohm, which seems reasonable. 
I don't know about any method you can compensate that.

Answer (score 3):

> Apart from this is there any other way to retain the same voltage to
>   draw the same current rate, so the power remains same?

I'd consider using a buck boost converter like this: -

[image]

I'm not saying the device above is a perfect match for what you want but you asked for other ideas how to solve it and this is a common enough technique to deal with drooping battery voltages.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage difference can be reduced by using short length wires depending on your application. I faced the same problem with 100m cable to power my device.

One solution is already presented to use a buck boost converter.

But ready-made solutions are available in market with names as DC-DC voltage stablizers, once such example is from Newmar link below.

https://www.poweringthenetwork.com/dc-power-stabilizers/

But many are available as you search, hope this helps you.

Comment: P.S. I am not promoting any product. I randomly searched and got this one and you can get many